# jquery cancel parent function

Tags: jquery, parent, each, preventdefault

Is there a method in jQuery similar to `retun false;` in function that prevents a parent function from running?

I've got a system outlined below, that needs to be stopped when a value is incorrect. Along with it, the parent function needs to be stopped.

```
parent.each(function(){

    child.each(function(){

        if (true) {

            //stuff
        } else {

           return false and cancel parent.each();
        }

    });

    otherChild.each(function(){

        if (true) {

            //stuff
        } else {

           return false and cancel parent.each();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parent.each(function(){
    var canceled=false;

    child.each(function(){

        if (true) {

            //stuff
        } else {
           canceled=true;

           return false;
        }

    });

    if(!canceled) otherChild.each(function(){

        if (true) {

            //stuff
        } else {
           canceled=true;
           return false;
        }
    });
    return !canceled;
});
```

Comment: I upvoted because this is a clean way to cancel the parent `.each()`, but the OP should note that if one was using a `for` loop instead of `.each()`, you could just return when you were done and not have to keep track of this flag and test it in multiple places.  These types of flow-of-control issues are sometimes handled simpler in `for` loops all in one funtion rather than `.each()` callback functions.

Comment: just for my understanding- what purpose does the final return !canceled server?

Comment: @technopeasant that breaks you out of the parent.each() loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 is right - a for loop is cleaner and more efficient.